# Do i need to know java or swift/objective-c to build apps with react native?

Tags: android, ios, swift, reactjs, react-native

If yes, how much proficiency is needed in these languages? Or can I straightly go to learn `React/React-Native` after learning `JavaScript`.

This may attract some opinions, but not purely an opinion based question as some expertise is needed.

Comment: no proficiency is needed but someday, and that day may never come, you may call upon to make little changes in native side. But until that day libraries will be very sufficient and maybe you will never need to make any changes on native side.

Answer (score 2):

In order to pick up React, you should understand JavaScript and npm on a good level.

When it comes to React Native, understanding Xcode on a basic level will be beneficial. Android experience might come in handy too if you are interested on the Android target.

Read this [reference](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-prerequisites-to-learn-React-js-and-react-native-build-What-is-the-difference-between-both-of-them) for more information.